# how to pass function to different DLL included in project as reference

Tags: c#, dll

I have referenced one DLL (I have source code of this) say Dll_A in which there is a function

```
private void uploadPic(int a)
```

In my main project, I have a function say

```
private void passMe(int b)
{
}
```

I need to pass the above function (`passMe`) to `uploadPic` function in Dll_A, how can I do that? Is it possible?
I am able to use functions of the Dll_A from my main project, so instantiating isn't a problem, I just need a way to pass function.

===
Thanks, giving it a try. If some can edit code below

```
//code in main project  picbackman.cs
public delegate void delObj(int v);
private void uploadSome(string path, string fName, string str)
{
delObj del1 = new delObj(updatePValue);
UploadFileResponse response =  boxProvider1.UploadFiles(args1, folderString, ((Picbackman.BoxProvider.delObj)( del1)));
}
//code in different dll which is referenced in main project //Dll_A                     

public delegate void delObj(int v);
public UploadFileResponse UploadFiles(string[] filePathes,string folderId, delObj d)
{}
```

Comment: how can you pass a function when the `uploadPic` takes int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your *method* will need to accept a delegate as one of it's parameters. That would be something like

```
private void uploadPic(Action<int> func,int a){
   //at some point do func(someInt);
}
```

at another point declare anothe method or function

```
public class someClasse {
   public vois passMe(int b){
  ...
  }
}
```

First of all notice that the access modifier has changed. if they are not in the same class you will need to be able to access one from the other so they can't both be private and since they are in different assemblies internal won't work either.

when you need the delegate do like this

```
var obj = new someClass();
var myInt = 5; //or whatever the value is
uploadPic(obj.passMe,myInt);
```

notice that the method is used with out arguments. When using a method without arguments the compiler will try and convert it to a suitable delegate.

I'd recommend you not to use `delegate` but stick with Func/Action they are delegates but more generic

```
public delegate void DelObj1();
public delegate void DelObj2()

public void F(){};

var del1 = new DelObj1(F);
var del2 = new DelObj2(F);
```

you can't pass a del1 where a DelObj2 is needed even though you use the same method for each. You will not have that issue if you use Action/Function

```
Action del1 = F;
Action del2 = F;
```

The reason is that DelObj1 and DelObj2 are two distinct classes with the same base class Ie they are siblings in the type tree. Using `Action` the type is the same for both del1 and del2

Comment: Thanks, giving it a try. If some can edit code below

    //code in main project picbackman.cs
    public delegate void delObj(int v);
    private void uploadSome(string path, string fName, string str)
    {
    delObj del1 = new delObj(updatePValue);
    UploadFileResponse response =  boxProvider1.UploadFiles(args1, folderString, ((Picbackman.BoxProvider.delObj)( del1)));
    }
    //code in different dll which is referenced in main project //Dll_A      

    public delegate void delObj(int v);
    public UploadFileResponse UploadFiles(string[] filePathes,string folderId, delObj d)
    {}

Comment: The code is rather unreadable as a comment. Post it as part of the question instead

Comment: I have edited my original question for explanation, I dont know how to post as part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [`Delegates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

From the documentation:

> A delegate is a type that references a method. Once a delegate is
>   assigned a method, it behaves exactly like that method. The delegate
>   method can be used like any other method, with parameters and a return
>   value

and

> Delegates allow methods to be passed as parameters

So in your case you should be able to do something like this:

```
// define the delegate
public delegate int PictureDelegate(int value)

// define your passMe function (in the class MyClass for example)
public int passMe(int value)
{
    return value + 1;
}

// when you want to use it
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
PictureDelegate passFunc = new PictureDelegate(myInstance.passMe);
myDll.uploadPic(passFunc, 12);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But when I try to pass delegate it says cannot convert THIS TYPE to THAT TYPE .. 

Nawfail : I can edit that function to accept function in addition to int which it is accepting. I just don't know how to do that

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a code sample that seems to correspond to your case. HTH

Comment: @sujit if you had the luxury to modify the dll function, then its easy. You could use delegates as shown or the built in Func delegates

Comment: Thanks, Yannick I am able to understand your code, but what should be the definition (or signature) of the function uploadPic in Dll_A.. I mean to say how should I define it there?

void uploadPic([WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE], int num)
{}

Comment: Following the code above, it should be something like `void uploadPic(PictureDelegate func, int num) {}` HTH

Comment: I have edited my original question, can someone help me. I am very bad with delegates